# Unable to add files with name containing tilde, '~' followed by a number

Tags: git, indexing, msysgit, tilde

The folder consists of files with filenames like `abc~1`, `123~1`, `a1d2~3`.

When I do `git add --all` it says,

```
$ git add --all
error: Invalid path 'abc~1.png'
error: unable to add abc~1.png to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

I did a trial and error and I found this error persists only when the tilde symbol is followed by a number.

If the folder is tracked by git for the first time, the other files are also not tracked by Git.

```
$ git clean --dry-run
Would remove Rest.png
Would remove abc~1.png
```

Please help how do I fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you even want to add all those files with ~ in their names? looks like editor generated temp files to me..

Comment: Yes, those images with filenames (abc~1.png) are used in java code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the result of a change that was made to msys Git [in December 2014](https://github.com/msysgit/git/commit/2e2a2d12).

> On Windows' default filesystems, FAT and NTFS, DOS-style 8.3 file names are
> supported for backwards compatibility. That means that there are multiple
> ways to reference the same file. For example, the file
> credential-cache--daemon.c can also be accessed via CREDEN~1.C (unless
> another file has already been mapped to that so-called "short name", i.e.
> the exact short name is unpredictable).
>
> Since this mapping is unpredictable, we need to disallow such file names on
> Windows, and while at it, we also exclude other file names incompatible with
> Windows' file systems (e.g. NUL, CON, etc).
>
> We use the core.protectNTFS guard introduced in the previous commit to make
> sure that we prevent such file names only when appropriate.

To disable this behaviour, you can run:

```
git config core.protectNTFS false
```

However, since the new behaviour is there to protect you, I’d recommend
changing it back after having added your files:

```
git config core.protectNTFS true
```

Only disable this protection when you need to add files with tildes in the
name or check out branches containing such filenames.

In general, I’d recommend avoiding such filenames if working in
a Windows environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anthony for the link and solution provided.

Comment: Nice find, +1. Can this be circumvented with a `-f` flag in `git add`?

Comment: @mu無 No, it can't. Saby, Glad to be able to have helped. I'll bet you won't be the only one affected by this. I've proposed an edit so others can more easily find this question.

Comment: thank you for this answer - it helped a lot. windows really has annoying filesystem limitations - my problem was caused by a file with a dot at the end