# .gitignore not working when directory starts wih ~

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory in a project which only contains a single file called chat.log. The directory is named ~. Yeah, just that. And it is located in the root of the project. I tried to add the directory and/or the file to .gitignore, but nothing seems to work. I tried adding:

```
~
~/*
*/chat.log 
chat.log
```

But really, nothing seems to work. What do I do?

Comment: What is the output of you running git status?

Comment: Why would you put a tilde in the name? You're just asking for trouble. Welcome to trouble land

Comment: This was the output:         modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   ~/chat.log

Comment: And yeah, I know it's asking for trouble, but I got the project like this, and I don't think I can go around renaming stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: If it says the chat log file is modified this means git is already tracking the file, .gitignore is not consulted when determining if a tracked file has modified, only when determining which files to add to the index.

Answer (score 2):

Is the file already added to the project? As in, Git is currently tracking it?
I don't know about folders, but [Git is not always happy about files containing tilde.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294910/unable-to-add-files-with-name-containing-tilde-followed-by-a-number)

Comment: Yeah, the file was being tracked. I deleted it and added /~/*.log to .gitignore, this worked. Thanks for the link, man.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file and adding /~/*.log to .gitignore did the trick.