# Git, adding folders containing tilde ~

Tags: git

I'm forced to create some folders with tildes in their name. Like, `~144455502343~`. I cannot check these into git.

This answer came up, but it does nothing. I'm on a Mac so the NTFS thing shouldn't affect me.

I'm using git version 2.11.0

[Unable to add files with name containing tilde, '~' followed by a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294910/unable-to-add-files-with-name-containing-tilde-followed-by-a-number)

Anyone know what to do to check in folders containing tildes?

// edit

I mean I cannot add them. The folders are ignored completely. They are not in my `.gitignore` but they also do not show up when doing `git status`, `git add \~144455502343\~`.

// edit

Looking for the spot where this is ignored.

Comment: `cannot check` ? do you mean you cannot add/remove/do anything in git with these files ? `\\` works fine on linux ( and i assume mac is similar )

Comment: Hi, have you tried `git add \~144455502343~`

Comment: @PriyeshKumar yes, I cannot add these.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot add"? Is Git displaying an error message? What is its output? What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: I mean it's literally ignored, everywhere.

Comment: Added pictures.

Comment: Your `git add` seems to have worked. The fact that there's nothing in `git status` would just indicate that the file you copied from work-tree to index by `git add`ing matches the version of the file that is in the `HEAD` commit. Try `git ls-tree -r HEAD` to see precisely what's in `HEAD`, or `git ls-files --stage` to see what's in the index now.

Comment: @torek as per `git status --ignored` I see them have a stray ignore file somewhere... trying to track it down

Comment: @Jorg: normally if some file is ignored and you pass the name directly to `git add` you see a complaint: `git add git-worktree <br>  The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: <br>  git-worktree <br>  Use -f if you really want to add them.` (StackOverflow will eat the line breaks here, so I replaced them with `<br>` for display)

Comment: @torek trying to find that file. The guys on the answer below have been helpful so far, but I haven't found it

Comment: @torek if the folder `foo/` is ignored, you only get a warning if you try to add `foo`. If you try to add `foo/` you interstingly do not get the warning. Might be a bug though.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot add these"?  Is there an error?  If you're trying to add a file that's ignored, you should get a message about that.  If you're adding a directory and it's simply not picking it up, it's likely that it's being silently skipped--which is exactly how ignores should work.  It's pretty common to ignore things with leading tildes (~) since Emacs uses it for backup files.  I'd check your config and make sure you aren't ignoring all files with leading tildes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `git add \~144455502343\~/` and nothing happens, it is likely ignored.

If you run `git add \~144455502343\~` and the folder is ignored, you will be hinted that the path is ignored.

To find out what pattern where ignores this, use `git check-ignore -v \~144455502343\~` which will show you the exact file, line and pattern that ignores this path.

I guess you have something like `*~` somewhere, as some text editors name backup files like that.

If this is the case and you want to keep the pattern, just use `git add -f ...` to force adding the file despite the ignoring. As soon as it is added, `.gitignore` is non-effective.

Comment: It's this, although I have not found the ignore that checks the `~`. I have learned a bit about git though.

Comment: Why didn't you? `check-ignore` tells you exactly.

Comment: I've tried this in the comments of the other answer but I get no results for any variation of `git check-ignore -v "*~"`, the path to the folder directly or the entry listed in `git status --ignored`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the tilde characters as follows:

```
git add \~144455502343\~
```

Comment: My local testing proves otherwise (Mac). Do these directories contain files? You cannot add an empty directory in git.

Comment: I know, I added some screenshots. The folder is not empty, `git add` gives no feedback, and the folder is not added. `git status` tells me it's up to date and the folder is not already in the repo

Comment: @Jorg How about `git status --ignored`, in case the folder is ignored by some other gitignore configuration?

Comment: My guess is that you are ignoring `*~` somewhere, since these are editor backup files.

Comment: @ElpieKay Now we're getting somewhere... it's in there. It's not in my local `.gitignore`. Where can I find the global one?

Comment: @Jorg Check `git config --global -l`, and see if you have `core.excludesfile` defined

Comment: @Jorg check the content of `.git/info/exclude`, the value of `core.excludesFile` in `git config --list`, the content of `~/.config/git/ignore`.

Comment: Run `git check-ignore -v \~144455502343\~` it should give a helpful debug output to show why the file name is ignored

Comment: @ElpieKay wow, nothing. a commented out mention of `~*` in `.git/info/exclude`. I have no `core.excludesFile` set and `~` does not appear in `~/.config/git/ignore`. I'll check if homebrew left any traces anywhere.

Comment: @Jorg You could also just use `git add -f` which allows adding of ignored files.

Comment: @crea1 yes I guess I might have to run with that.I prefer not.

Comment: @Jorg Just found this command `git check-ignore -v "*~"`. It should print out which ignore file the rule is located in.

Comment: @crea1 no results.

Comment: As @Peter and @crea1 suggested, you could try `git check-ignore -v *` before `git add -f` to list all the ignored files and where the configuration is defined.

Comment: The output is `.gitignore:6:node_modules node_modules` and nothing else.

Comment: @Jorg have you run `git add -f`? If yes, remove them from the index first by `git rm -r --cached ~144455502343~`.

Comment: ironically, the new git client removed them for me. so, there are no files added from that folder (or: `did not match any files`).