# C# Sharpcompress error handling files containing tilde ~

Tags: c#, compression, tilde, sharpcompress

Fist up I am what I would call a copy and paste coder, learning through trial and error.

I am working on a personal project to extract a pile of compressed files (of varying compression types) to a single folder so they can then be processed. A number of these compressed files include a tilde (~) either in the file name or the name of a compressed file.

All of these files with a tilde break with an exception error... all other files are working as expected so I have narrowed it down to the tilde being the root cause and validated this my manually editing a compressed file and replacing the ~ with _ and everything works.

Here is the error that is collected by the exception:

> 2023-11-19 13:07:30,023 [ERROR] - Extract Source Compressed Files: Entry is trying to write a file outside of the destination directory.

Here is my code, which is pretty much copy and paste from the example given by SharpCompress:

```cs
public static void extractcompressedfiles_mk2(string Compressedfilepath, string extractPath)
{
    // If directory already exist, CreateDirectory does nothing
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPath);
    try
    {
        // Extract current zip file
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(Compressedfilepath))
        using (var reader = ReaderFactory.Open(stream))
        {
            while (reader.MoveToNextEntry())
            {
                if (!reader.Entry.IsDirectory)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Entry.Key);
                    reader.WriteEntryToDirectory(extractPath, new ExtractionOptions()
                    {
                        ExtractFullPath = true,
                        Overwrite = true
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Common.Globals.intExceptionErrors++;
        Logging.system.Error($"Extract Source Compressed Files: {e.Message}");
    }
```

I did find the following question that might provide more insight - [Unable to add files with name containing tilde, '~' followed by a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294910/unable-to-add-files-with-name-containing-tilde-followed-by-a-number)

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can resolve or circumvent this error, my plan B is to use 7zip and run the commands via Windows but this feels naughty!

Cheers
Euge

Comment: This could be a problem relating to short file names (8.3 notation). See: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces / Short vs. Long Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names): *On many file systems, a file name will contain a tilde (~) within each component of the name that is too long to comply with 8.3 naming rules.*. The file system could assume that it is a 8.3 filename and try to expand it to a long file name

Comment: This answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) explains it better than me: [Answer to: Copying files with tilde has odd behaviour](https://serverfault.com/a/607590).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one vital bit of information I missed is that the tilde is in the middle of the filename. I don't think this is related to how Windows is interpreting the files as when handling them natively in Windows they are behaving as expected. Its only when the tilde is the penultimate character I would expect it to cause an issue... but i could be wrong on this.

Is there a way to rename the file before its written to replace the tilde with _ ?

Comment: You could try something like `System.IO.File.Move(filename, filename.Replace("~","-"));`, this effectively renames the file if the directory remains the same.